# Best Practice for calling a method programmatically where the methodName is -(void)animatePageX where x =1 thru 25

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, dynamic

I am doing a children's book using Leaves.  I want to have a different animated image and sound play for each page.  I have figured out how to do the animation, I have it in a method that i can pass all the animation objects for each page.  But each page is so different that I am ending up writing a different method for each page.  I have a pageNum var that I want to call each pages method page 5 animation method would be `-(void)animatePage5`,  and so on.

But I can not figure out how to build the method call so that it has the pageNum object in it.

I know this is easy, but I just can not find an answer on google, or stack overflow.

I might be too close to the forest to see  the trees.

What is the simple, best practice for this type of method call.

Thanks for helping out a noob....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a switch statement to redirect the method call to the right method:

```
-(void)animagePage:(int)pagenum
{
    switch (pagenum) {
        case 1: [self animatePage1]; break;
        case 2: [self animatePage2]; break;
        case 3: [self animatePage3]; break;
        ...
        case 25: [self animatePage25]; break;
    }
}
```

Or you can create a string and then convert it to a @selector:

```
NSString* methodName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"animatePage%d", pagenum];
SEL aSelector = NSSelectorFromString( methodName );
[self performSelector:aSelector];
```

Comment: Fantastic.  This works great.  Exactly what I wanted to do.  Worked on first shot.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about an 'easy' solution, I've certainly never needed this before.

I think this is a step to what you're looking for, but I'd consider refactoring your code so the method takes a parameter like suggested in the other answers: `-(void)animatePage:(int) page`

```
NSString *selectorName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"animatePage%d", pageNumber];
SEL s = NSSelectorFromString(selectorName);
if ([self respondsToSelector:s]) [self performSelector:s];
```

Comment: Could possibly have a `respondsToSelector` call as well, for safety. Gets my superhero vote.

Comment: @nacho4d good spot. Even when you said 'fixed the string' I couldn't think what I'd done. Added your check too jrturton

Answer (score 3):

A simple answer would be to have a method called `-(void)animatePage:(int)page` where you either have a massive switch statement containing your code from each method, or just a call to each method.

However, I eagerly await an objective-C superhero suggesting doing something clever with `@selector` or method swizzling or some other scary technique.

Comment: I've had to have a go at that! [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808658/best-practice-for-calling-a-method-programmatically-where-the-methodname-is-vo/7808899#7808899)

Comment: Well, the animation works fine.  However, NOW,  I can not get the animation to end, quit, or hide after the animation plays.

Comment: You should ask a new question as that is a separate problem. You'll need to post some of your animation code I expect.